# Samsung Galaxy s6 stuck in boot

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-6

My galaxy s6 is stuck in what appears to be the boot phase, where the logo is flashing on and off so the screen is not frozen.

[image: Galaxy s6 stuck in boot phase with flashing screen]

I have tried:

- Holding the start button and power button
- Holding the start button, power button and volume up button
- Plugging the phone into the computer to try and flash it, but the computer won't recognise it

Before it was like this, I was trying to unlock the phone with my fingerprint. The screen froze for a minute then went into what is currently being displayed (see picture).

Is there anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hard resetting it, works in many cases of soft brick.

Force close your phone, hold power button + volume down for 10 seconds. Phone should power off.

Now hold volume up + power button, phone should boot in recovery. From there select Delete data and cache then reboot.

You'll lose all your data stored in the phone memory but phone should work normally.